# Getting error object HTMLHeadingElement when I use document.querySelectorAll

Tags: html, jquery

When I use `document.querySelectorAll`, I get error:

> object HTMLHeadingElement

### DEMO:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x, i;
  elements = document.querySelectorAll("[id].example");
  vals=Array.from(elements)
alert(vals);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <h2 class="example" id = "1">A heading with class="example"</h2>
    <p class="example" id = "2">A paragraph with class="example".</p> 
    <p class="example" id = "3">A paragraph with class="example".</p> 
    <p class="example" id = "4">A paragraph with class="example".</p> 
    <p class="example" id = "5">A paragraph with class="example".</p> 
    <p class="example" id = "6">A paragraph with class="example".</p> 
    <p class="example" id = "7">A paragraph with class="example".</p> 

    <p class="hi" id = "4">A paragraph with class="example".</p> 



    <p>Click the button to add a background color all elements with class="example".</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p><strong>Note:</strong> The querySelectorAll() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

I want the values of the id so I tryied this method, showing this as the value But I got output like:
[image: object HTMLParagraphElement]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want only values of IDs then you can simply do this.

```
function myFunction() {
  var x=[];
  elements = document.querySelectorAll(".example");
  elements.forEach(function(el){
    x.push(el.id);
  })
  vals=console.log(x);
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5w7Lbprh/

Comment: thanks a lot, That works well how can i access them

Comment: If this answer help you a little, please mark this answer as accepted by clicking on ✓ check icon on left side of this answer.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this

Comment: how to get each id

Comment: You can access each element individually within forEach section. What do you want to do with the id?

Comment: i want to insert into a text field

Comment: Where is the text field in your HTML?

Comment: actually i use oracle apex

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the Oracle apex code there? or Create a jsfiddle so that I can understand where you want to use the id retrieved by above js.